# Do processes have a chance to terminate safely after wsl.exe --terminate?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Do processes have a chance to terminate safely when the user calls `wsl.exe --terminate` or `wslconfig.exe /t` to terminate a distribution on WSL? I'd also like to understand if there's any difference between WSL2 and WSL1 in this respect. On linux, my understanding is that `shutdown(8)` sends `SIGTERM` to all processes, which gives them a chance to save and exit cleanly. Is this the case in WSL too through the terminate commands?

Comment: I just want to say: _don't get discouraged because your question was closed_.
It was closed because it was considered off-topic for Stack Overflow.
(Actually I disagree with that verdict – I think your answer demonstrates that the question is indeed about _programming_.)
What you could do is ask the exact same question again (and also post your answer) at [Super User](https://superuser.com).
Your question is fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone coming here, there appears to be no clear documentation on what the terminate commands do under the hood, but based on a little experimentation I don't believe they send any signals to the processes, and the behaviour is the same for WSL1 and WSL2.

Here's some sample code to trap `SIGTERM` (can be modified for any signal).

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t sigterm_flag = 0;

static void sigterm_handler(int _)
{
  (void)_;
  sigterm_flag = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  signal(SIGTERM, sigterm_handler);

  while (1) {
    if (sigterm_flag) {
      puts("Terminated by SIGTERM");
      break;
    }
    sleep(1);
    puts("Still running...");
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compiled this and ran it. Then I ran `wsl.exe --terminate` or `wslconfig.exe /t` or `wsl --shutdown` from a separate powershell tab. No signals are trapped by the program and the WSL instance simply exits. Sending signals directly using `kill` works as expected and prints the trapped signal before exiting.

If anyone can shed some light on what actually happens when you call `--terminate` that would be useful. Also, thanks to [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/jaavag/do_processes_have_a_chance_to_terminate_safely/g8oxm2e/) for some help.